# unable to force a small image from inheriting the transparency of the parent elament

Tags: html, css, inheritance, transparency

I am in the final stages of developing a website for a client and am having much difficulty figuring out how to prevent a small  flower image from inheriting the transparency of it's parent element.

I first tried making the image independent, using absolute positioning in the css. This worked; however, it introduced an alignment issue depending on the size of the browser window and size the the monitor and also the operating system. I was able to eliminate (somewhat) the browser issue by adding in browser selection javascript and adding the requisite css code to check for each browser, but I was still running into the alignment issue depending on the size of the browser window and size of the monitor screen.

To view the page with the independent floating (flower image), please see the following url:

[mauisunsetb122.com/index5.html](http://www.mauisunsetb122.com/index5.html)

I then decided to tie the image to the adjoining text so that no matter the size of the browser window or monitor, the image will always be anchored to the text. this is where the transparency issue occurred.  To see an example of this please see the following url:

[mauisunsetb122.com/index5_8.html](http://www.mauisunsetb122.com/index5_8.html)

I tried resolving the issue by following the example found at the following url, but it didn't work:

http://blog.ninanet.com/2010/04/27/css-transparency-inheritance-hack

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: mauisunsetb122.com/index5_8.html link not works

Comment: apply `opacity:0.4`  for the image

Comment: @ krishnan If I understand correctly, opacity can only be set in css and because the image is tied to the description div (and it's class), I do not see how I can add an image class in css and then add a class setting to the image in html? Unless I can add the image and its opacity to the .description css. I could certainly be wrong, but I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to make the background transparent and not have the child elements inherit this then you have several options:

1. Use a small PNG with transarency as the background image.
2. Set the background color using rgba 'background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);'
3. Use horrible css hacks

Generaly 1 seems to be the most used and supported.